# Как правильно переписать блочное чтение файла под .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, io

Есть нативный метод, который выполняет подсчет переносов строк при блочном чтении файла:

```
static uintmax_t FileLinesCounter(std::wstring &path)
{
    uintmax_t lines = 0;
    static const size_t BUFFER_SIZE = 16 * 1024;
    char buffer[BUFFER_SIZE];
    DWORD blocks_read = 0;
    LARGE_INTEGER distance = { 0 };

    HANDLE fp = CreateFileW(
        path.c_str(),
        GENERIC_READ,
        FILE_SHARE_READ,
        NULL,
        OPEN_EXISTING,
        FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL | FILE_FLAG_SEQUENTIAL_SCAN,
        NULL);

    if (fp != NULL && SetFilePointerEx(fp, distance, NULL, FILE_BEGIN) != INVALID_SET_FILE_POINTER)
    {
        while (ReadFile(fp, buffer, BUFFER_SIZE, &blocks_read, NULL) && blocks_read > 0)
        {
            for (char *p = buffer; (p = (char*)memchr(p, '\n', (buffer + blocks_read) - p)) != 0; ++p)
                ++lines;

            if (SetFilePointerEx(fp, distance, NULL, FILE_CURRENT) == INVALID_SET_FILE_POINTER)
                break;
        }
        return lines;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Я пытаюсь портировать его под .NET, вот что получается:

```
internal async static Task<BigInteger> FileLinesCounter(string filePath)
{
    BigInteger result = 0;
    const int bufferSize = 16 * 1024;
    var buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

    using (var fs = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read, buffer.Length, FileOptions.SequentialScan))
    {
        while (await fs.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length) > 0)
        {
            result += Array.FindAll(buffer, b => b == (byte)'\n').Length;
            Array.Clear(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Проблема в скорости работы, нативный метод работает в разы быстрее, в чем я ошибся?

p.s. аналога `memchr` в дотнете не нашел, поэтому пришлось использовать `Array.FindAll` =(

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/75830/discussion-on-question-by-user1-------).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте код:

```
var count = File.ReadLines("...").LongCount();
```

Даже если файл будет полностью состоять из однобайтовых переводов строки, то переменной типа long хватит на файл размером 8 эксабайт (10<sup>18</sup>).

Убедиться что `File.ReadLines` считает не только `\r\n`, но и одиночные `\r` или `\n`, можно с помощью такого простого кода:

```
var text = "1\r\n2\r3\r4\n5\n6\n7";
File.WriteAllText("1.txt", text);
var count = File.ReadLines("1.txt").LongCount();
Console.WriteLine(count);
```

Выведет `7`

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте вот такое

```
var fname = @"C:\....";

using (var reader = File.OpenRead(fname))
{
    ulong num = 0;
    var nline = '\n';
    var buffer = new byte[16 * 1024];
    int len = 0;
    do
    {           
        len = reader.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
        for(var i=0; i<len; i++) if (buffer[i] == nline) num++;         
    }while(len > 0);    

    Console.WriteLine(num);
}
```

у меня оно работает чуть быстрее, чем `File.Readlines()`